# C# equivalent of Visual Basic API call

Tags: c#, vba

I have inherited a API which gives a Visual Basic example of how to call the API which is below:

```vb
Dim sPost As String
Dim sAction As String
Dim sXMLData As String
Dim sHTTPHeaders As String
sPost = "POST"
sAction = "http://MyHost/1/XmlService"
sXMLData = "<xml ..> <request …….. /></xml>"
sHTTPHeaders = "Content-type: text/xml"
Inet1.Execute sAction, sPost, sXMLData, sHTTPHeaders
```

I am familar with using HttpWebRequest and have no issue setting the content type, method etc but I am not sure how to set the sXMLData - which property of my HttpWebRequest would I set?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you'd want to write that XML data to the request body.  To do that, you normally create a StreamWriter using `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()`:

```
// HttpWebRequest request;
// string sXmlData;

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    sw.Write(sXmlData);
}
```

Comment: And once is done I would have request.GetResponse() I presume?

Comment: @andrew-buchan yes, right -- similarly, you use `var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())` to get the response data.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as calling `UploadString` on a `WebClient`:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
    wc.UploadString(sAction, sXMLData); // (url, data) .. default method is POST
}
```